# How to treat 'empty',0,NULL as the same in MySQL ORDER BY statement

Tags: mysql, sql, null, isnull, sql-order-by

I am using a database that I have no real control over (3rd party system) and one of the tables allows the 'featured' column to be either EMPTY,0,1, or NULL.

Any of the states EMPTY,0,NULL mean the same thing.

I ORDER BY the 'featured' column, then ORDER BY the 'name' column, but the resulting data is not in alphabetical order, except grouped by 'featured' in alphabetical lists.

```
FEATURED   |          NAME
--------------------------
1          | Apple
1          | Orange
0          | Avocado
0          | Banana
0          | Cauliflower
NULL       | Broccoli
NULL       | Potato
           | Cabbage
```

Basically, I need to have 0, NULL, EMPTY treated as the same value, so they are all ordered alphabetically.

Example of ideal output

```
FEATURED   |          NAME
--------------------------
1          | Apple
1          | Orange
0          | Avocado
0          | Banana
NULL       | Broccoli
           | Cabbage
0          | Cauliflower
NULL       | Potato
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them last, I would do this with an expression like this:

```
order by (featured is null or featured = '0' or featured = ''),
         name
```

You could simplify this to:

```
order by ((featured > 0) and featured is not null) desc, name
```

If you like.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out with:

ORDER by IF(featured IS NULL or featured = '', 0, featured) DESC, name ASC

Which is basically the same as your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To get `'0' or '' or NULL` values to be sorted together, I would use an expression that "converts" two of those values into the third, so that the same value is returned in all three cases.

It appears that the `featured` column is character type, so I'd avoid unnecessary implicit datatype conversions, and my preference would be a fairly short expression.

To get the `NULL` and `'0'` converted to a `''`, so the rows were sorted first (in ascending sequence), I'd do something like:

```
  ORDER BY IFNULL(NULLIF(featured,'0'),''), name
```

If I wanted to return a `NULL` as the common value (so those rows got sorted last in ascending sequence), I'd convert the `''` and `'0'` into `NULL`, something like this:

```
  ORDER BY NULLIF(NULLIF(featured,'0'),''), name
```